# Android App Bundles - Is it possible to upload multiple app bundles in one release?

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, multi-project, android-app-bundle

We have a legacy project, that consists of two projects:

- one for phones.
- one for tablets.

Each project has it's own structure, it's own classes, resources, etc. Both have the same package name, are signed with the same keystore and are uploaded as two `.apk` files with the same version and consecutive build numbers as single app.

**Question**

Is it possible, without merging these two projects, to keep uploading them as App Bundles like we did with `.apk`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as I understand it you can have multiple App Bundles per release like you did for APKs. Like before they have to have different version codes. It will make your release management a little complicated, but it should work.

Comment: To be honest it is already messy with two .apks, so it won't become more problematic :) Just curious, did you try it, or is it just an assumption?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I work on Google Play with the people who wrote the App Bundle code, so if it doesn't work I'll go and tell them it's broken.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Will try and get back to you with more info :)